# Is this a good Cherry Tomato spacing?

Tags: tomatoes, cherries, spacing

As the title says, is this a good spacing for cherry tomato plants?

[image]

Comment: These are 'starts'...they should be individually transplanted as soon as possible in 3" pots.  Otherwise, I'd let them go to see how this works out.  Planting vegetables in pots that are too large is a mistake.  So far you have a few plants that are viable where ONE of these plants should be all that is necessary for that pot.  Do not over water.  Only water shallowly for these starts or you will lose them to fungus.  Those roots need to be large enough to help suck up the water so the water doesn't encourage fungus in the wet soil.  Did you use potting soil, are there drain holes?

Comment: I am hoping this is sterilized potting soil.  Hopefully you've not added gravel or rocks below the soil and above the drain holes.  Lift the bottoms of these pots off their saucer using 1/4" tile pieces.  Never allow water to sit in the saucers.  Don't fertilize until you've got at least 3 sets of leaves and then use a boring balanced NPK where the N is lower in percentage to the P and the K.